# Iterate hashmap in struts 2 and based on its value check or uncheck a checkbox

Tags: jsp, checkbox, struts2, hashmap

I need to iterate over a hashmap using struts 2 and if hashmap's value is true i need to check the checkbox else keep it unchecked.

I have been able to iterate over map but i am not able to put conditional check inside it. If hashmap's value is true i need to check the checkbox if it is false i need to keep unchecked. How to use if clause inside iterator to check hashmap's value.

Below is the code snippet i am using

```
testMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
testMap.put("1","true");
testMap.put("2","false");
```

==================================================================================

```
<struts:iterator value="testMap.entrySet()"> 
     <input type="checkbox" name="abc" value='<struts:property value="%{value}"/>'>   
     <struts:property value="%{value}"/>
```

Comment: Why not to use `struts:checkbox`?

Comment: Checkbox is fine but the question is how to conditionally put checked="checked" clause in checkbox whenever hashmap's value is true

Comment: Struts will put that based on the value attribute.

Comment: Can you please provide code snippet/example of how it will work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet/example of how it will work

```
<struts:iterator value="testMap"> 
     <struts:checkbox name="abc" value="%{value}"/>   
     <struts:property value="%{value}"/>
</struts:iterator>
```